# How can I add a second texture apart from the one I'm using with displacement modifier?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, displacement

I'm trying to work my way through the desert tutorial by Andrew Price. I have a landscape with a displacement modifier with clouds texture (Type:Clouds). So my landscape has already one texture assigned to it. Now I added some grass with particles and I'm trying to add a material to that grass (particle system is assigned to the same landscape). In the tutorial the grass material is based on a another texture (Type:Blend). The problem is that I can't add a second texture - I can only modify the texture which is used by displacement modifier.
The main reason for this problem is that Andrew is using Blender internal renderer and I'm using cycles.

So the question is: is there a way in cycles to add second texture (Type:Blend) without deleting/modifying the one assigned to displace modifier (Type:Clouds)?

Comment: If you add the textures from the displace modifier, then from the particles panel (textures section), you'll have these two textures available in the texture panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you can still have different textures when using cycles. However that way you add them, and access them is a little different.

When you are using cycles you no longer start your texture in the texture tab of the properties window (like how you had to do it for particles), now much like the displace modifier there is a button to jump right to your texture.  [image: "Show texture in texture tab" button]

[image: animated gif - showing the process for creating a texture]

Now for the particle system, you do much the same thing as for the displace modifier.

1. Go to the particle tab and add a new texture.
   [image: texture in particle tab]
2. Click on the "*Show texture in texture tab*" button. (You could also go to the texture tab your self, more on that in a bit.)
3. You are now editing the texture for the particles, set what ever influences you want.

[image: animated gif - showing the process for adding a texture to a particle system]

---

The texture tab works a little differently then when you are using the blender internal.
In cycles all the textures are nicely broken up by category, and you can edit any of them at any time.
[image: textures in texture tab]

While you can make new textures and assign them to different uses (say I make a new texture for the displace modifier, I can switch right in the texture tab.)
However you can not add new texture uses from the texture tab. So if you do not already have the displace modifier using a texture you can not assign a texture to it in the texture tab.

Comment: Thank you for great help - of course it works perfectly! Cheers